# Package 'python-pybabel' has no installation candidate

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, odoo-8, ubuntu-16.04

I do install odoo version 8 in ubuntu version 16 ,
then I  doing like this link https://www.getopenerp.com/easy-odoo8-installation/
. In step 3 , it is wrong  it say "E:Package 'python-pybabel' has no installation candidate". what happens?

Answer (score 2):

python-pybabel was replace by python-babel package from what I see on the web search.
After I face also this problem I use python-babel and all work correctly.

best regards,
CiprianR

Comment: Could you include the updated command you used to install python-babel? It may seem trivial but this question is asking how to install, an answer should include the installation command.

Answer (score 1):

This python-pybabel has been replaced by another package called python-babel. So try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-babel
```

This should work

Answer (score -1):

Hello this is a command for dependencies, you need to run it :

```
sudo apt-get install python-psutil python-pybabel
```

Comment: does not solve the problem, after this command it says: "E: Package 'python-pybabel' has no installation candidate"